# How to change Edit/Done button title in UINavigationBar in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm displaying an editButtonItem in my tableview but I need to change the text of Edit and Done to Change and Cancel. All the examples I've found so far are in Objective-C... I need Swift syntax.

I have the following in viewDidLoad function...

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
```

... which displays the standard Edit/Done button item.

Comment: Not a duplicate... look at the context of the questions...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you want to work on `setEditing` method

```
override func setEditing (editing:Bool, animated:Bool)
{
   super.setEditing(editing,animated:animated)
   self.editButtonItem.title = editing ? "Cancel" : "Change"
 }
```

and add the following line in viewDidLoad()

```
 self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.title = "Change"
```

Comment: Uday.M Thanks... this partially works. On initial load of view the button still displays Edit... but on clicking it correctly displays Cancel and once I click Cancel it then becomes Change.

Comment: OK Done it... added self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem!.title = "Change" after self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem() in my viewDidLoad()